# Capturar un valor select en una vista de django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

No sé como capturar el valor de un select de un formulario creado a partir de un ModelForm. 
en el template:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="{{formulario.cod_sucursal.id_for_label}}"> 
{{formulario.cod_sucursal.label}}</label>
   <select name="{{formulario.cod_sucursal.id_for_label}}" id="{{formulario.cod_sucursal.id_for_label}}" class="custom-select form-control">
     <option value='0'>Selección de Sucursal</option>
       {% for opciones in formulario.cod_sucursal %}
         {{opciones}}
         {% endfor %}

   </select>
</div>
```

El formulario está cortado porque es más largo.

Lo que se renderiza es :

```
<form action="/tablaventas/recibo" method="post">

  <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='0w3Y3WLmT6rbN488ohtG36LUMcS2t6XrhDu3X26V7fecg35kMkOzyv5kNXTRFu1Z' />

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="encabezado-cod_sucursal">Cod sucursal</label>
        <select name="encabezado-cod_sucursal" id="id_encabezado-cod_sucursal" class="custom-select form-control">
          <option value='0'>Selección de Sucursal</option>

          <option value="600">Pilgrim</option>

          <option value="200">Mandiola</option>

          <option value="100">Fch</option>


        </select>
      </div>
```

el views.py para la función es:

```
def tablaventas_recibo(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    formu=VentasFormSet(request.POST, prefix='detalle') # formset 
    encabezado=tablaVCPFormulario(request.POST, prefix='encabezado') # Formulario
    print(encabezado.errors)
    if formu.is_valid() and encabezado.is_valid():
        codigo_sucursal=encabezado.cleaned_data

        co = formu.cleaned_data[1]
        print(codigo_sucursal)
        return HttpResponse('gracias')


return HttpResponse(encabezado.errors)
```

y el ModelForm es:

```
class tablaVCPFormulario(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model=VentasContrapuntoPilgrim
    fields='__all__'
    widgets = {
       'titulo': TextInput,
       'edicion': TextInput,
       'fecha_contable':SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class': 'custom-select'}),
       'cod_sucursal':SelectMultiple(choices=codigos_sucursal),
    }
    exclude = ('saldo','inicial','isbn',)
    prefix='encabezado'
```

la salida de error me dice me falta ingresar *cod_sucursal*, justamente que está en el select del html en el template, pero no tengo idea qué me faltará para que se capture y se envíe en el post.
Muchach@s, desde ya, muy agradecido.

Comment: Creo que esta linea está mal: `<select name="{{formulario.cod_sucursal.id_for_label}}"` y deberia ser: `<select name="{{formulario.cod_sucursal.name}}"` ya que `id_for_label` le agrega sufijo al nombre del campo y seguramente por eso django no lo está recibiendo como es

Comment: Gracias Germán. Lo que posteaste me saca el error de encima pero captura "None" en vez de capturar el valor del option. A parte de la documentación de Django, ¿hay algo más?

Comment: A lo mejor debe ser un error de valores y cuando django lo pasa por el método `to_python` no está reconociendo algo, puedes intentar agregar los option de manera dinámica y no estática. La forma más facil es reemplazar todo tu `select` (incluyendo el label) en html y cambiarlo por `{{ formulario.cod_sucursal }}` de esta forma debe servirte, y si es por estilos, puedes agregarlos  como haces en tu formulario con `fecha_contable`

Comment: gracias germán!